# How to generate grouping numbers based on remove selection in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

Lets say I have a sequence set of integer number from 1 to 85 in data:

```
data = [1:1:85];
```

If I choose removeselection = 0, answer should be equal to data (all number from 1 to 85).

If I choose removeselection = 1, answer should be 85 groups of data.

```
data1 = [2:1:85] %remove number 1;
data2 = data(:,2) = []; %remove number 2
data3 = data(:,3) = []; %remove number 3
.
.
.
data85 = data(85,:) = []; %remove number 85
```

If I choose removeselection = 2, answer should remove 2 number and generate 85(84) group of data.

If I choose removeselection = 84, answer should be 85 group consist of single number.

```
data1 = [1];
data2 = [2];
data3 = [3];
.
.
.
data85 = [85];
```

If I choose removeselection = 85, answer should be equal to 0

The function should enable user to put number of removeselection from 0 up to maximum numbers in data which is 85.

Please help me regarding the matter. I really stuck on this xD

Comment: Do you realize that with `removeSelection = 42` you have 3.3e+024 (=`nchoosek(85,42)`) groups of data?

Comment: Yups, and that's the problem of it. I am thinking of selecting few random group of data (limit 300 set) for removeselection which gives too much groups of data for example.

Comment: For choosing a random group of data: use `randsample` (see updated answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in one line, using [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html). But note that, as I stated in the comments, the number of groups of data may become very large.

```
data = [1:1:6]; %// example data
removeSelection = 3; %// how many data to remove

groupsOfData = data(nchoosek(data,numel(data)-removeSelection));
```

In the example, the result is:

```
groupsOfData =

     1     2     3
     1     2     4
     1     2     5
     1     2     6
     1     3     4
     1     3     5
     1     3     6
     1     4     5
     1     4     6
     1     5     6
     2     3     4
     2     3     5
     2     3     6
     2     4     5
     2     4     6
     2     5     6
     3     4     5
     3     4     6
     3     5     6
     4     5     6
```

If there are too many groups of data and you want to sample randomly (as you state in the comments), you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
randomGroupOfData = randsample(data,numel(data)-removeSelection);
```

Comment: Wow, it is really what I wanted!! Thanks Luis Mendo!!